# CIC compensation filter and total response

Tags: filters, filter-design

**UPDATE**: New plot with properly scaled CIC comp response.
[image]

I'm studying about CIC filters for interpolation/decimation and I'm reading about CIC compensation filters due to CIC filters not having a flat freq response in the passband. So I ran the code in [this Application Note](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/an/an455.pdf) (Example 1) by Altera on "understanding CIC compesation filters" and I have 2 questions:

1. How can I obtain the total filter response? If I have $H_{cic}(z)$ and $H_{comp}(z)$, total response should be $H(z)=H_{cic}(z)H_{comp}(z)$, which I believe would result in the convolution of both filters' coefficients. But this is what I got:
   [image: Plot of total response for CIC and CIC comp]

   It doesn't look good at all. Is this the right way to get the total response?
2. On page 7 it says

   > In a multirate compensation filter, a decimation compensation filter with
   >   a rate change factor of 2 has input sampling rate fS/R and output
   >   sampling rate (fS/R)/2. To avoid aliasing, the compensation filter must
   >   have a cutoff frequency that is no more than half of (fS/R)/2, that is,
   >   (fS/R)/4.

   Where in the example (I mean, where in the code) do you decide that the compensation filter has a rate change factor of 2? And does that mean that the final output signal will have sampling frequency of $f_s/R/2$ instead of $f_s/R$?

Thanks!

Comment: If the curve for *CIC Comp* is what it should be, I'd argue that yes, that's the right method of combining these two. Wild guess, though: You're plotting filters that run at different rates into the same frequency axis, and that might lead to confusion.

Comment: That's true! That's why it didn't look too good to me. But that makes me wonder if it is a good compensation filter at all then, since the total response is still not flat in the passband

Comment: does it still look bad if you thought the CIC to be say 8 times as broad, and the compensation filter thus operated only on the relatively flat part of the passband of the CIC?

Comment: well even though the blue curve is wrong (since it should be narrower), I guess the total response curve is still running at the same rate than the CIC filter, isn't it? Even if i try to zoom there's no such thing as flat. I updated the main post with a plot where the CIC comp response is scaled. Although I was thinkning, if final cutoff freq is 4.85e6, that'd mean i want it to be flat (0 dB) between 0 and 4.85e6/91.392e6=0.053? In that case, it already is flat without even compensation.

Comment: hey, your absolute frequencies mean nothing to me, because you haven't told us your sampling rate so far. No, what you describe wouldn't be the case: the whole point of the CIC is that you get an extremely efficient filter that you use to decimate as far as feasible, and then in the very last step when your sampling rate is already low, you use a last stage "straightening" decimating FIR. If your CIC passband is flat, it's not the full passband – and you'll run into aliasing.

Comment: Oh sorry, as i said in the main post, i'm running the example found here  https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/an/an455.pdf so the input to CIC filter is $f_s=91.392 MHz$, the decimation rate is $R=4$ and the cutoff frequency for the CIC comp filter is $f_c=4.85 MHz$. I haven't changed any value from the example, so I assume that code is correct. I'm just plotting the curves which they didn't do and trying to understand how the CIC compesation filter works. As I understand from the app note, the output $f_s=91.392/(2R)=11.424 MHz$.

Comment: And I get what you mean, but i think the total response should be somewhere between the CIC (red) and Cic comp (blue) curves from 0 to approximately 0.1 (absolute freq in the plot)